# How to check if the value is present under array and difference is less than of 0.000002

Tags: javascript

I have got a set of values in a array .

I am checking for two conditions ,

1.`If the value is present in the array` 
**OR**
2.`The difference is less than 0.000002`

then 
I need  to alter the value .

I was able to do it for the first condition (If the value is present in the array)

Could you please let me know how can i satisfy the second condition also  (if the difference is less than 0.000002)

This is my first condition

```
 if (lats.indexOf(parseFloat(lat))!=-1) {
                lat = parseFloat(lat)+parseFloat(0.111);
               lat = lat.toFixed(4);
            }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/af4e8m63/6/

Comment: difference of...from what  difference you mean?

Comment: the difference of current latitude present with in that lats array

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
found = myArray.some(function (item) {
   return Math.abs(item - searchValue) < 0.000002
})
```

Do note, however, that such small numbers are not exact, so for example

```
111.000002 - 111
```

will be

```
0.0000019999999949504854
```

Comment: @PreethiJain: it's not very clear to me what your code does. Could you edit the question and tell us more about the ultimate goal?

Comment: please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/af4e8m63/6/ and there you will find a condition  if (lats.indexOf(parseFloat(lat))!=-1) , or which i need to add your second condition

Comment: The markers are so close , so if they are so close i want to alter the marker values so that they will be shown clearly without overlapping.